# SQL Server User Permission Error Messages

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute a database script I created through the Forward Engineer Addin for Microsoft Visio. Initially, when I executed the first time on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, it executed. However, when I changed the diagram in Visio, created a new script and re-executed the script, I received the following errors:

> Msg 5011: User does not have permission to alter database
>   Msg 5069: ALTER DATABASE statement failed
>   Msg 3701: Cannot drop the database because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

It ran the first time I executed. I did not change any settings prior to attempting to re-execute the script. But why am I receiving the aforementioned errors?

How do I ensure the user using to execute the script has access to modify database properties and create database permissions?

Comment: Cannot drop the database because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to make sure the user you are using to execute the script has access to modify database properties and create database permissions.

Comment: How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, Locate the "Security->Logins" item under your database server. If you cant find your username/group there, Rightclick on Logins and click "New Login", otherwise double click on your login to update permissions.  You can specify the security permissions in "Server Roles".

Comment: Which permissions should I select to avoid the error messages? I don't want to arbitrarily select them all.

Comment: It depends on the scenario, ideally you want to give the minimum permissions to allow it to work. dbcreator, sysadmin and the owner of the db will allow you to drop the database. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258843(v=sql.80).aspx